# Eclipse RCP change Task-Icon of Splash-Screen

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a Splash screen in my Eclipse RCP project. While the application is loading (and splash-screen is shown) there is the eclipse-icon shown in the taskbar. Is it possible to change the taskicon?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what icon you need to change (it would be easier for people to figure out the solution :))

Answer (score 1):

In your .product file, you should configure the launcher information (launcher name and icons).  Once you have those defined, the icons should be bound into the launcher and those icons should be displayed in the windows taskbar while the splash screen is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you start the application from Eclipse, the splash screen has the Eclipse icon but the application will have the proper icon.

Try exporting the application, it should work with proper icon for splash screen too.